# How to use the imageview id in activity_main.xml in another package?

Tags: android, kotlin

[activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enxrv.png)

[I want to use it in the FaceDetector.kt file here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zemNH.png)

imageView2.setImageBitmap(~) like this..

Comment: Please do not post an image of code.

Comment: Please see deep links or navigation alongside multi-modular app

Comment: Could you please share the code of FaceDetector.kt?

Comment: Please read [mre] before posting any question.